# Android getting ANR after upgrade of this app

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I am getting ANR at one of the screen in my app. Below is the trace
DALVIK THREADS (39):

```
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c9c0a0 self=0xb7e0fc38
  | sysTid=21975 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4538930
  | state=R schedstat=( 28940155 2916720 15 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb443c000-0xb443e000 stackSize=1014KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 0035ca4d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+116)
  native: #01 pc 0033d8a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+138)
  native: #02 pc 00347213  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+422)
  native: #03 pc 00347d5b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+194)
  native: #04 pc 00348281  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+124)
  native: #05 pc 00348969  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+312)
  native: #06 pc 00321dfd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+68)
  native: #07 pc 00328ee3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13HandleSigQuitEv+910)
  native: #08 pc 003297f3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+390)
  native: #09 pc 00041acb  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #10 pc 00019355  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c9e0a0 self=0xb7e12480
  | sysTid=21976 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4434930
  | state=S schedstat=( 453565788 49893271 254 ) utm=45 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb4338000-0xb433a000 stackSize=1014KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 000430fc  /system/lib/libc.so (__pselect6+20)
  native: #01 pc 0001b4c5  /system/lib/libc.so (select+60)
  native: #02 pc 003ea7df  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+202)
  native: #03 pc 0025b2d3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+298)
  native: #04 pc 0025c13f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+10)
  native: #05 pc 00041acb  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #06 pc 00019355  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Native
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c992e0 self=0xb7dfb3f0
  | sysTid=21980 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa4b1c930
  | state=S schedstat=( 1027995840 75087763 196 ) utm=99 stm=3 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xa4a1a000-0xa4a1c000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 000169b8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000f60bb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 001bc91f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap27TrimIndirectReferenceTablesEPNS_6ThreadE+1370)
  native: #03 pc 001bcbf1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12HeapTrimTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+40)
  native: #04 pc 001ce4f1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+40)
  native: #05 pc 00000387  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+74)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Sleeping
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c99280 self=0xb7dd2e90
  | sysTid=21979 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4120930
  | state=S schedstat=( 1154845 11608229 27 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb401e000-0xb4020000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep!(Native method)
  - sleeping on <0x0cedeaed> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
  - locked <0x0cedeaed> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:273)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:284)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:232)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c99220 self=0xb7dfb8e0
  | sysTid=21978 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4227930
  | state=S schedstat=( 512972345 70567081 2806 ) utm=29 stm=22 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb4125000-0xb4127000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0f2f6d22> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
  - locked <0x0f2f6d22> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c991c0 self=0xb7e021c0
  | sysTid=21977 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb432e930
  | state=S schedstat=( 287206659 80040521 3908 ) utm=10 stm=18 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb422c000-0xb422e000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x04be03b3> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:147)
  - locked <0x04be03b3> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74d492a0 self=0xb7bfef28
  | sysTid=21970 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f8db34
  | state=R schedstat=( 21014676824 802481866 5665 ) utm=2043 stm=58 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe08c000-0xbe08e000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  at in.comp.customviews.RobotoLightTextView.setTypeface(RobotoLightTextView.java:29)
  at android.widget.TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs(TextView.java:1496)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1391)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
  at in.comp.customviews.RobotoLightTextView.<init>(RobotoLightTextView.java:22)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance!(Native method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
  - locked <0x097a4d70> (a java.lang.Object[])
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at in.comp.adapters.recyclerviewadapter.MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.java:37)
  at in.comp.adapters.recyclerviewadapter.MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.java:23)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5464)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4689)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2600)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1092)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:632)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1149)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:729)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

[Detailed log is here](https://pastebin.com/vTHdwvyZ)

Couldn't paste it here as it exceeded character limit.

About the structure:

The screen is divided in two parts. Both parts have two recycler views. Left side has a recyclerview. On selecting option from left side, the data gets populated on right side's recyclerview. Some data array are too large. So, whenever any option is selected, I update the data of second recyclerviews adapter. Couldn't figure out why is it throwing ANR.

Comment: Are you running multiple threads here?

Comment: @RuchiraRandana No, I already have all data sets. When an option is selected from left side's recyclerview, I change the data set of right sides recycler view. The only thing is, some of arrays are quite large containing about 1000 elements. Recently, I updated my app to API 23. Then only this problem appeared.

Comment: try updating support libraries also

Comment: @Nilabja Thanks it was problem with support library only

Comment: @Nitish How exactly did you fix this problem?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat That was issue with support library. That's why it was loading all 1000 views at once. I didn't changed anything on code level. I only updated support library package.

Comment: @Nitish How did you do that?